# wProxy problem url in server mod build in nuxt js

Tags: nuxt.js

I have two proxy in nuxt.config.js.

```
 axios: {
    proxy: true,
    baseURL: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
      ? "process.env.BASE_URL"
      : "http://192.168.13.5:5000",
    proxyHeaders: true,
    credentials: true
  },
 proxy: {
    '/test1/': {
      target: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production"
        ? "http://192.168.1.2:5000"
        : "process.env.BASE_URL", pathRewrite: {'^/test1/': ''}
    },
    '/test2/': {
      target: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production"
        ? "http://192.168.1.3:5000"
        : "process.env.BASE_URL", pathRewrite: {'^/test2/': ''}
    },
  },
```

My proxy works fine and removes `test1` in API request in dev mode, but when I built the project for production, I have a `test1` or `test2` at URLs.

Comment: unclear what you mean, perhaps place the process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production" on the outer object, i.e `proxy: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production" ? {...} : {}`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would like to recommend adding `basePath` at the beginning of the **nuxt.config.js** file

```
const basePath = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production"
  ? "http://192.168.1.2:5000"
  : "process.env.BASE_URL";
```

And replace `process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production" ? "http://192.168.1.2:5000" : "process.env.BASE_URL"` with `basePath` everywhere.

So we will get the next code:

```
  axios: {
    proxy: true,
    baseURL: basePath,
    proxyHeaders: true,
    credentials: true
  },
  proxy: {
    '/test1/': {
      target: basePath, pathRewrite: {'^/test1/': ''}
    },
    '/test2/': {
      target: basePath, pathRewrite: {'^/test2/': ''}
    },
  },
```

and it should work now.

Also, you need to check that `process.env.NODE_ENV` is not `undefined` in production mode, otherwise you need to define it for the script to work correctly.